# vscode jupyter failed to start kernel

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter, vscode-extensions, anaconda3

I use jupyter notebooks in vscode all the time. I noticed about a day or two ago that I could no longer run code  in cells. It always displayed

`Failed to start the Kernel.  OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '"c:'.  View Jupyter log for further details.`

The logs also show

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '"c:'... View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (c:\Users\XY_User\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.6.1201981810\out\extension.node.js:24:230120)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)] {
  category: 'kerneldied',
  kernelConnectionMetadata: {
    kind: 'startUsingPythonInterpreter',
    kernelSpec: {
      specFile: 'c:\\Users\\XY_User\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.7.1001951036\\temp\\jupyter\\kernels\\python383jvsc74a57bd0ad2bdc8ecc057115af97d19610ffacc2b4e99fae6737bb82f5d7fb13d2f2c186\\kernel.json',
      interpreterPath: 'c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe',
      isRegisteredByVSC: 'registeredByNewVersionOfExt',
      name: 'python383jvsc74a57bd0ad2bdc8ecc057115af97d19610ffacc2b4e99fae6737bb82f5d7fb13d2f2c186',
      argv: [Array],
      language: 'python',
      executable: 'python',
      display_name: "Python 3.8.3 ('base')",
      metadata: [Object],
      env: {}
    },
    interpreter: {
      id: 'C:\\PROGRAMDATA\\ANACONDA3\\PYTHON.EXE',
      sysPrefix: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3',
      envType: 'Conda',
      envName: 'base',
      envPath: [w],
      architecture: 3,
      sysVersion: '3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 17:30:36) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]',
      version: [Object],
      companyDisplayName: 'ContinuumAnalytics',
      displayName: "Python 3.8.3 ('base')",
      detailedDisplayName: "Python 3.8.3 ('base': conda)",
      uri: [w]
    },
    id: '.jvsc74a57bd0ad2bdc8ecc057115af97d19610ffacc2b4e99fae6737bb82f5d7fb13d2f2c186.c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe.c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe.-m#ipykernel_launcher'
  },
  exitCode: 1,
  stdErr: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n' +
    '  File "c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\ipykernel\\kernelapp.py", line 248, in init_connection_file\r\n' +
    "    self.connection_file = filefind(self.connection_file, ['.', self.connection_dir])\r\n" +
    '  File "c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\ipython_genutils\\path.py", line 71, in filefind\r\n' +
    '    raise IOError("File %r does not exist in any of the search paths: %r" %\r\n' +
    "OSError: File 'c:\\\\Users\\\\XY_User\\\\AppData\\\\Roaming\\\\jupyter\\\\runtime\\\\kernel-v2-7868dLFyv3ry3NTk.json' does not exist in any of the search paths: ['.', 'C:\\\\Users\\\\XY_User\\\\AppData\\\\Roaming\\\\jupyter\\\\runtime']\r\n" +
    '\r\n' +
    'During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    'Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n' +
    '  File "c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main\r\n' +
    '    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,\r\n' +
    '  File "c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code\r\n' +
    '    exec(code, run_globals)\r\n' +
    '  File "c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>\r\n' +
    '    app.launch_new_instance()\r\n' +
    '  File "c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\traitlets\\config\\application.py", line 663, in launch_instance\r\n' +
    '    app.initialize(argv)\r\n' +
    '  File "<decorator-gen-125>", line 2, in initialize\r\n' +
    '  File "c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\traitlets\\config\\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error\r\n' +
    '    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)\r\n' +
    '  File "c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\ipykernel\\kernelapp.py", line 565, in initialize\r\n' +
    '    self.init_connection_file()\r\n' +
    '  File "c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\ipykernel\\kernelapp.py", line 252, in init_connection_file\r\n' +
    '    ensure_dir_exists(os.path.dirname(self.abs_connection_file), 0o700)\r\n' +
    '  File "c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\ipython_genutils\\path.py", line 167, in ensure_dir_exists\r\n' +
    '    os.makedirs(path, mode=mode)\r\n' +
    '  File "c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\os.py", line 213, in makedirs\r\n' +
    '    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)\r\n' +
    '  File "c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\os.py", line 213, in makedirs\r\n' +
    '    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)\r\n' +
    '  File "c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\os.py", line 213, in makedirs\r\n' +
    '    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)\r\n' +
    '  [Previous line repeated 3 more times]\r\n' +
    '  File "c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\os.py", line 223, in makedirs\r\n' +
    '    mkdir(name, mode)\r\n' +
    `OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '"c:'\r\n`,
  vslsStack: [ CallSite {}, CallSite {}, CallSite {} ]
}
info 2:51:27.573: Process Execution: > c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe -c "import ipykernel"
> c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe -c "import ipykernel"
```

This topic seems to recur a lot so I found and tried these but no dice.

1. `python -m ipykernel install --user`
2. checking the `kernel.json` file in `anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/` directory.
3. switching between pre-release and release versions of the jupyter extension

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this can be caused by a mismatch between the version of `ipykernel` installed by anaconda and the base requirements of the `jupyter` plugin for vscode.

My case was solved with the following steps.

1. Launch an instance of anaconda prompt
2. Type `pip install -U ipykernel --user` and hit enter
3. Switch to vscode and push `Ctrl + Shift + P` and enter `Developer: Reload Window`
4. Try executing a cell in your `.ipynb` file

Hope this helps someone out there.